# MongoDB C# driver 1.10.0 conflicts in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've created a simple Azure Mobile Services project and added the nuget package for MongoDB (package id is mongocsharpdriver).
The version I added is **1.10.0**
When I deploy the project I get the following error:

**"Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'MongoDB.Bson': 1.10.0.62. Please change your project to use version '1.9.2.235' which is the one currently supported by the hosting environment."**

It seems like the Dlls from the package I've added are conflicting with an older version installed by default in the cloud environment.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

(While trying to figure out whats wrong I installed the nuget package **WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Mongo** which can't be installed because it requires mongocsharpdriver(=1.9.2) and dose not allow me to use my newer dlls.)

Comment: Do you need exactly version 1.10.0? If not just downgrade to the supported version 1.9.2 (http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/1.9.2). Just remove the nuget package and add the specific version.

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/cQ_1lS2_cd0) I'll have to wait for microsoft to update the dll in Azure: